# Rectangular printer prgram

Tags: java

1. Prompt the user for the height and width of a rectangle that will be displayed as rows and columns of asterisk (*) characters.
2. Using your knowledge of loops, generate the rectangle output. The height will be the number of rows and the width will be the number of characters in each row. Since your output will be generated one row at a time, make sure you complete each row before moving on to the next.
3. Modify your program so that it generates only the outside border of a rectangle rather than a filled rectangle.

I dont know how to get the asterisks to line up in rows and columns.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int width;
        int height;     

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

        System.out.print("Enter the width:");
        width = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the height:");
        height = input.nextInt();
        int y = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x <= width; x++){
            System.out.println("*");
            while (y <= height){
                y++;
                System.out.println("*");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to get an output that looks something like this for width = 4 height = 4

```
****    ****
****    *  *
****    *  *
**** or ****
```

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your cord.

Comment: @Conan Please be civil. Laughing at someone asking a question is not helpful.

Comment: Hint: Use `System.out.print()` instead of `System.out.println()`.

Comment: You may want to investigate `System.out.print` or `StringBuilder`

Comment: Welcome to [so]! What does the output look like, now? Make sure to always build an [mcve] before asking for debugging help. The #1 reason is, it teaches you how to solve these problems without needing our help, by helping you concentrate on all the right things. The #2 reason is, it makes it much easier for someone else to provide a meaningful answer quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few tips to help you figure this out:

1. println() always prints a newline character after the value you pass in. You probably only want that at the end of each line, not after each character.
2. You don't need a while loop - you can do all of this work using two for loops.
3. Break down what you need to achieve into smaller chunks and solve each chunk separately.

For example, a solid square (written as an algorithm, not as code):

```
loop y once for each row {

    loop x once for each column in that row {

        print a '*' character

    }

    print a newline character (because we have finished the row)

}
```

For example, a hollow square (written as an algorithm, not as code):

```
loop y once for each row {

    loop x once for each column in that row {

        if the current position is in the first row, last row, first column or last column
            print a '*' character
        otherwise
            print a ' ' character
    }

    print a newline character (because we have finished the row)

}
```